# Better to use a Mac or PC to develop for Typescript?

Tags: macos, typescript

I'v got access to both, but I would prefer to stay with the Mac, unless there are going to be major drawbacks from trying to develop with TS on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

No major drawbacks at all. I use TS on mac and it works just fine! If I were you, I would stick with mac. On Mac, everything is just so much easier to use (in my opinion)!

Comment: Same question here, is there a way to auto-compile typescript on a mac?